# filter solr inner query with outer query values

Tags: solr, lucene, inner-query

Is there, in SOLR, a way to use values from outer query in inner query.

Basically what i want to do, is to compare two documents

I have made SQL equivalent query. But no idea how to implement in SOLR

```
select * from Versions v1
    where 1=1
    and v1.ItemId in (select ItemId from Versions where v1.ItemId = ItemId AND v1.Checksum != Checksum  AND [From] <= '2016-01-01' and [To] >= '2016-01-01')
    and v1.[From] <= '2015-01-01' and s1.[To] >= '2015-01-01'
```

As a result i would get all version which have actually change between given time range

Comment: Have you tried these [Solr join examples](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join)?

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but check https://lucidworks.com/blog/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/ -- you might also google for "solr correlated subquery"